# Find full FPO and ATPO Number for Intel CPU from Software

Tags: cpu

My CPU Is damaged so I need to start the RMA Process, but my computer is running. I don't want to disassemble the CPU Fan just to read the visible numbers from the CPU and then reassemble. Is there a way to get the FPO/ATPO #'s Intel wants via Software I can run inside Windows or Linux? I tried CPU-Z but didn't see the info I needed :'*(.

Thanks!

Comment: See this page...https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000021613/processors/intel-core-processors.html

Comment: I'm more than familiar with that but at that point I can just use the visible numbers. I don't want to disassemble my CPU fan

Comment: I don't think it's possible atm :(. Hope somebody at Intel reads this.

Comment: The more votes, the more Intel will see the desire for this information :)

Comment: I should state that Intel was fabulous with the RMA, offered me to pay a deposit to have the chip sent to me before I returned mine or they would let me send in mine and then get the replacement free of charge. I ended up upgrading my CPU/MOBO and selling the new CPU after the RMA

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any software which can solve your problem, but the FPO and ATPO are printed on the box of the CPU, at least in my case. You'll find the FPO as "Batch#" and the ATPO as "S/N" on the box of your CPU.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: while your answer is help it is more of a comment as "FreeSoftwareServers" wanted a bit of software to tell him. This is a comment you will over time get the right to comment in the mean time please take a couple of minutes and read:- [help] .Answering: [answer], again welcome to superuser.Thankyou